# Django : cannot reverse URL to generate sitemaps

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I am currently trying to generate a sitemaps.xml using Django. To do that, i followed the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) but I have troubles to generate the sitemaps for the following type of urls :

```
url(r'^duo/(?P<pseudo>[a-z]+)/$','clients.views.duo', name='duo')
```

My *sitemaps.py* is looking like that :

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from datetime import datetime

class SiteSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):

def __init__(self, names):
    self.names = names

def items(self):
    return self.names

def changefreq(self, obj):
    return 'weekly'

def location(self, obj):
    return reverse(obj)
```

and the part containing the sitemaps in *urls.py* like that:

```
sitemaps = {
'pages':SiteSitemap(['homepage',
                    'landing_page',
                    'mentions',
                    'no_anim',
                    ]),
}

urlpatterns += [
     url(r'^sitemap\.xml', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
]
```

When passing 'duo' on its own, I have the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml

Reverse for 'duo' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['duo/(?P<pseudo>[a-z]+)/$']
```

and when I try to pass arguments in this way ('duo', 'anna'), I have the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml

Reverse for '('duo', 'anna')' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I am encountering a syntax error which is rather logic as reverse() does not accept triple parenthesis. However, I do not see how I can fix this. Does anyone have a clue about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the correct syntax for using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) is:

```
reverse('duo', args=['anna'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your location method to following :

```
def location(self, item):
    return reverse('url_name', args=(arg,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answers, I did this little piece of code, hope it can be of any help for others users:

```
def location(self, obj):
    if len(obj) == 1:
        return reverse(obj[0])
    else:
        return reverse(obj[0],args=[obj[1]])
```

*obj* are tuple objects declared in *urls.py*